# Debian 8 - Enabled .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess, debian

My server turn on Debian 8 (Jessie).

I try to enabled htaccess on apache, so I edited

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and I changed

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

into

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        #Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now the .htaccess file is working on, but when I put the login/password and submit, I got the error:

```
500 Erreur interne du serveur
```

(500 internar server error)

So what is the right way to enabled htaccess files on Debian 8 ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please take a look into your http servers error log file. That is the place where the server logs issues to. It should _always_ be the first thing you do if you encounter problems with your web stuff.

Comment: I have nothink special, just the line: "193.248.45.67 - "" [25/Jun/2015:18:46:36 +0200] "GET /site/ HTTP/1.1" 500 802 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" each time I refresh...

Comment: No, that is the access log. The error log is a separate file.